# How can I add proxy with IP/port and username/password in CurlHttpClient on Symfony HttpClient Component?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, php-curl, symfony-http-client

I'm using Symfony HttpClient Component, it became necessary to use it with a proxy. Open proxy with the port, I can easily configure with the default configuration when instantiating CurlHttpClient class, but I can't set username and password for private proxy

Example of default configuration:

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\CurlHttpClient;

$httpClient = new CurlHttpClient([
    'http_version' => '2.0',
    'proxy' => 'x.xx.xxx.xxx:8000',
]);
```

I try to add additional configuration on the extra options, and try other combinations, but can't find the right way.

with plain PHP and cURL everything works fine.

Please, help me, configure the Symfony HttpClient Component with a private proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify protocol (e.g. `socks5`, `socks4` etc)

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\CurlHttpClient;

$httpClient = new CurlHttpClient([
    'http_version' => '2.0',
    'proxy' => 'socks5://username:password@127.0.0.1:9999',
]);

dump($httpClient->request('GET', 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json')->getContent());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,
any open proxy work fine without protocol specify

```php
$httpClient = new CurlHttpClient([
    'http_version' => '2.0',
    'proxy' => '187.44.167.78:60786',
]);


response is:
200 / 187.44.167.78
```

I try add private proxy with user login and password, like:
'proxy' => '127.0.0.1:9999:user:password'

private proxy does not work, with protocol and without protocol specofy.

Comment: I found the solution, the data for the proxy should be specified in the following format:

`'proxy' => user:password@ip:port`

it wors fine.

Comment: @GelaP. My bad, forgot to include main part to the answer, as test it on the local proxy

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, the data for the proxy should be specified in the following format:

```php
$httpClient = new CurlHttpClient([
    'http_version' => '2.0',
    'proxy' => 'user:password@ip:port',
]);
```

it wors fine